# Set Access Key on mobile using CSS?

Tags: css

I am learning how to code CSS for mobile. I need to know how to set access key using CSS? I already know how to set access key using HTML.

Comment: Why do you think access keys can be set with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the future, look at the rules for posting before asking a question. This question is easy to answer and possible a duplicate as well. However, I will answer your question, because I believe that good or not, a question deserves to be answered. In the future, provide your code as well so that we can give improvements on it.**

The simplest answer to your statement is that you cannot set an access key using CSS. This is because accesskey is a HTML attribute. If you want to style the object using the accesskey attribute simply set a class to that attribute. For example,
 `<a class=thisisaclass href="https://www.upvotemeplease.com" accesskey="h">Attribute</a>`